# Android Loop Through JSON to Download Images

Tags: android, json

I am using the following json string that contains URL filename of images:

```
{
  "images": [
    {
      "image_url": "https:\/\/placeimg.com\/150\/50\/nature",
      "image_filename": "placeimg_150_50_nature.jpg"
    },
    {
      "image_url": "https:\/\/placeimg.com\/150\/50\/nature",
      "image_filename": "placeimg_150_50_nature.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am also using this function to download the images to my SD card which works perfectly:

```
public void downloadFile(String uRl, String fileName) {

        File file = new File(getAppRootDir()
                + "/images", fileName);
        File direct = new File(getAppRootDir()
                + "/images");

        if (!direct.exists()) {
            direct.mkdirs();
        }

        if (!file.exists()) {
            DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

            Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(uRl);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    downloadUri);

            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
                    DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                            | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                    .setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle("Demo")
                    .setDescription("Something useful. No, really.")
                    .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(getAppRootDir() + "/images", fileName);

            mgr.enqueue(request);
        }
    }
```

How would I loop through the JSON to the get image_url and image_filename for each entry?

Comment: Which problem you are getting ?

Comment: just check out the GSON library. Handles parsing for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response is `JSONObject` which contents `JSONArray` with key `images` of JSONObject's.final `JSONObject` contents both keys.

Get `image_url` and `image_filename` keys values as:

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(<response_string>);
// get images JSONArray from jsonObject
JSONArray jsonArrImages=jsonObject.getJSONArray("images");
for(int index=0;index<jsonArrImages.length(); index++) {
  JSONObject jsonObjectInner=jsonArrImages.getJSONObject(index);
  String img_url=jsonObjectInner.optString("image_url")+"/"
                     +jsonObjectInner.optString("image_filename");

  // download image from url
   downloadFile(img_url,jsonObjectInner.optString("image_filename"));

}
```

Comment: This worked great! I just had to surround it in a try/catch but it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Gson library with conjunction with http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to easy create the parsing classes.
Will work wonderfully.